using std::bind on a member function with class arguments that has non-default copy constructor gives error?
I am trying to use std::bind on a member function with one argument, as below:
// tester.hpp
#include <functional>

class message
{
  public:
    message()
    {
    }
    //message(message &msg){value = msg.value;} // Uncommenting this line causes error
    int value = 0;
};

class messageHandler
{
  public:
    messageHandler()
    {
        handleIntFn = std::bind(&messageHandler::handleInt, this, std::placeholders::_1);
        handleMessageFn = std::bind(&messageHandler::handleMsg, this, std::placeholders::_1);
    }

  private:
    bool handleInt(int value)
    {
        return value == 0;
    }
    bool handleMsg(message msg)
    {
        return msg.value == 0;
    }

    std::function<bool(int)> handleIntFn;
    std::function<bool(message)> handleMessageFn;
};

This compiles with no problems, but giving the message class a copy-constructor causes the following error which I'm not sure how to fix:
/home/tester.hpp:19:92: error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'std::function<bool(message)>' and 'std::_Bind_helper<false, bool (messageHandler::*)(message), messageHandler*, const std::_Placeholder<1>&>::type')
   19 |         handleMessageFn = std::bind(&messageHandler::handleMsg, this, std::placeholders::_1);
      |                                                                                            ^
In file included from /usr/include/newlib/c++/10.3.1/functional:59,
                 from /home/tester.hpp:1,
                 from /home/tester.cpp:1:
/usr/include/newlib/c++/10.3.1/bits/std_function.h:396:7: note: candidate: 'std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>& std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::operator=(const std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>&) [with _Res = bool; _ArgTypes = {message}]'
  396 |       operator=(const function& __x)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/newlib/c++/10.3.1/bits/std_function.h:396:33: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::_Bind_helper<false, bool (messageHandler::*)(message), messageHandler*, const std::_Placeholder<1>&>::type' to 'const std::function<bool(message)>&'
  396 |       operator=(const function& __x)
      |                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/newlib/c++/10.3.1/bits/std_function.h:414:7: note: candidate: 'std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>& std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::operator=(std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>&&) [with _Res = bool; _ArgTypes = {message}]'
  414 |       operator=(function&& __x) noexcept
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/newlib/c++/10.3.1/bits/std_function.h:414:28: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::_Bind_helper<false, bool (messageHandler::*)(message), messageHandler*, const std::_Placeholder<1>&>::type' to 'std::function<bool(message)>&&'
  414 |       operator=(function&& __x) noexcept
      |                 ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/newlib/c++/10.3.1/bits/std_function.h:428:7: note: candidate: 'std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>& std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::operator=(std::nullptr_t) [with _Res = bool; _ArgTypes = {message}; std::nullptr_t = std::nullptr_t]'
  428 |       operator=(nullptr_t) noexcept
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/newlib/c++/10.3.1/bits/std_function.h:428:17: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::_Bind_helper<false, bool (messageHandler::*)(message), messageHandler*, const std::_Placeholder<1>&>::type' to 'std::nullptr_t'
  428 |       operator=(nullptr_t) noexcept
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/newlib/c++/10.3.1/bits/std_function.h:457:2: note: candidate: 'template<class _Functor> std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::_Requires<std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::_Callable<typename std::decay<_Functor>::type>, std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>&> std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::operator=(_Functor&&) [with _Functor = _Functor; _Res = bool; _ArgTypes = {message}]'
  457 |  operator=(_Functor&& __f)
      |  ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/newlib/c++/10.3.1/bits/std_function.h:457:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/newlib/c++/10.3.1/bits/std_function.h: In substitution of 'template<class _Res, class ... _ArgTypes> template<class _Cond, class _Tp> using _Requires = typename std::enable_if<_Cond::value, _Tp>::type [with _Cond = std::function<bool(message)>::_Callable<std::_Bind<bool (messageHandler::*(messageHandler*, std::_Placeholder<1>))(message)>, std::__invoke_result<std::_Bind<bool (messageHandler::*(messageHandler*, std::_Placeholder<1>))(message)>&, message> >; _Tp = std::function<bool(message)>&; _Res = bool; _ArgTypes = {message}]':
/usr/include/newlib/c++/10.3.1/bits/std_function.h:457:2:   required by substitution of 'template<class _Functor> std::function<bool(message)>::_Requires<std::function<bool(message)>::_Callable<typename std::decay<_Tp>::type, std::__invoke_result<typename std::decay<_Tp>::type&, message> >, std::function<bool(message)>&> std::function<bool(message)>::operator=<_Functor>(_Functor&&) [with _Functor = std::_Bind<bool (messageHandler::*(messageHandler*, std::_Placeholder<1>))(message)>]'
/home/tester.hpp:19:92:   required from here
/usr/include/newlib/c++/10.3.1/bits/std_function.h:319:8: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, std::function<bool(message)>&>'
  319 |  using _Requires = typename enable_if<_Cond::value, _Tp>::type;
      |        ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/newlib/c++/10.3.1/bits/std_function.h:466:2: note: candidate: 'template<class _Functor> std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>& std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::operator=(std::reference_wrapper<_Functor>) [with _Functor = _Functor; _Res = bool; _ArgTypes = {message}]'
  466 |  operator=(reference_wrapper<_Functor> __f) noexcept
      |  ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/newlib/c++/10.3.1/bits/std_function.h:466:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /home/tester.cpp:1:
/home/tester.hpp:19:92: note:   'std::_Bind<bool (messageHandler::*(messageHandler*, std::_Placeholder<1>))(message)>' is not derived from 'std::reference_wrapper<_Tp>'
   19 |         handleMessageFn = std::bind(&messageHandler::handleMsg, this, std::placeholders::_1);
      |

Is std::bind using the default copy constructor? Why can't I replace it with my own?
I'd expect it to be able to use a class with a copy constructor

The copy constructor must take const message &msg.

@273K That seems to fix it, thanks. Any tutorials on copy constructors I found didn't usually include a const, while I'm sure the default generated one does (and thus bind expects it to be marked const too?).
